# Overriding ProfileForm fields in Mezzanine

Tags: django, mezzanine

I have a User Profile ManyToManyField that by default, renders as a multi-select.  On the user's profile page, I would like to override this with a TextInput field that I can add auto-complete jquery to, but I'm having a hard time seeing where to do this in Mezzanine.

TIA,
Joel

Answer (score 0):

This is a Django question more than a Mezzanine question:

**Widgets** are what you need to set.

You're going to need a form definition, which you didn't mention.  In the form definition override the default widget section as shown below.  You can add class defs and more here too.

```
field_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'display:block;','class': 'form-control'}),required=True)
```

It can also be done after the declaration:

```
field_name.widget = forms.TextInput()
```

It can also be done in the **init** within the form class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.fields['field_name'].widget = forms.TextInput()
```

more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/widgets/